# C++ LNK2019 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, linker-errors, lnk2019

I have read many posts about LNK2019, but can't resolve this error.

Here is my code:

*Time.h:*

```
#ifndef PROJECT2_TIME_H
#define PROJECT2_TIME_H

#include<iostream>
using std::ostream;

namespace Project2  
{
class Time
{
    friend Time& operator+=(const Time& lhs, const Time& rhs);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Time& rhs);
public:
    static const unsigned secondsInOneHour = 3600;
    static const unsigned secondsInOneMinute = 60;
    Time(unsigned hours, unsigned minutes, unsigned seconds);
    unsigned getTotalTimeAsSeconds() const;
private:
    unsigned seconds;
};

Time& operator+=(const Time& lhs, const Time& rhs);
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Time& rhs);

}

#endif
```

*Time.cpp:*

```
#include "Time.h"


Project2::Time::Time(unsigned hours, unsigned minutes, unsigned seconds)   
{
    this->seconds = hours*secondsInOneHour + minutes*secondsInOneMinute + seconds;
}

unsigned
Project2::Time::getTotalTimeAsSeconds() const
{
return this->seconds;
}


Project2::Time&
Project2::operator+=(const Time& lhs, const Time& rhs)
{
Time& tempTime(unsigned hours, unsigned minutes, unsigned seconds);
unsigned lhsHours = lhs.seconds / Time::secondsInOneHour;
unsigned lhsMinutes = (lhs.seconds / 60) % 60;
unsigned lhsSeconds = (lhs.seconds / 60 / 60) % 60;
unsigned rhsHours = rhs.seconds / Time::secondsInOneHour;
unsigned rhsMinutes = (rhs.seconds / 60) % 60;
unsigned rhsSeconds = (rhs.seconds / 60 / 60) % 60;
return tempTime(lhsHours + rhsHours, lhsMinutes + rhsMinutes, lhsSeconds + rhsSeconds);
}

ostream&
Project2::operator<<(ostream& os, const Time& rhs)
{
unsigned rhsHours = rhs.seconds / Time::secondsInOneHour;
unsigned rhsMinutes = (rhs.seconds / 60) % 60;
unsigned rhsSeconds = (rhs.seconds / 60 / 60) % 60;
os << rhsHours << "h:" << rhsMinutes << "m:" << rhsSeconds << "s";
return os;
}
```

The main.cpp simply creates Time objects and uses the overloaded operators, doesn't seem like there can be problems(these codes are provided so are themselves good).

I have tried to remove the "&" behind all the "Time" symbol, and I got the same error.

**And here is the error message:**

> Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class Project2::Time & __cdecl tempTime(unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?tempTime@@YAAAVTime@Project2@@III@Z) referenced in function "class Project2::Time & __cdecl Project2::operator+=(class Project2::Time const &,class Project2::Time const &)" (??YProject2@@YAAAVTime@0@ABV10@0@Z) c:\Users\Eon-Gwei\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\c++III_Project2_GW\c++III_Project2_GW\Time.obj  c++III_Project2_GW

Comment: which symbol fails to link?  You need to provide the actual error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Time& tempTime(unsigned hours, unsigned minutes, unsigned seconds);` declares a function with the name `tempTime`, and `return tempTime(lhsHours + rhsHours, lhsMinutes + rhsMinutes, lhsSeconds + rhsSeconds);` calls that function. Since the function does not have an implementation anywhere, you get a linker error.

<strike>Since `operator +=` is presumably supposed to return a reference to the object it is invoked on, you should modify the object's member variables through `this` rather than creating a new `Time`, and return `*this`.</strike>
Edit: Any sane implementation of `operator +=` would modify the left-hand-side operand, rather than creating a new object. I suggest you reconsider how your operator should work.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to modify Time& lhs and return it, and the error was gone.

Comment: @aureus: Great! Please accept this as an answer since it solved your problem (in addition to giving me reputation points, that will prevent other people from thinking that this question still needs answering, and spending time on it needlessly).

Comment: @aureus: I believe you can still _accept_ answers, which is different from upvoting. (But I gave you an upvote, so now you only lack 4 points ;-) )

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! Now I have 6 reputation and 2 bronze badges.

Comment: I just found I can accept the your answer. Thanks, Aasmund.